# \gls is not compatible with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, warnings

I got this warning message:

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
> removing `\gls' on input line 39

Line 39 is the following: `\subsection{\gls{tev} protease cleavage}` is there any option to keep the `\gls` and the `\autoref` commands together?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: You should not use `\gls` inside sectioning commands. Replace it with `\glsentryname{tev}`

Comment: Thank you. It's working perfectly.